# Bash create variable then assign value to it

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

For this problem I have two values, ***curdir*** and  ***curlevel***, which change throughout my script. I want to know if it's possible to create a variable and then use that value as the name for another value. For example

```
temp="dir_${curdir}_${curlevel}"
$temp=$name_of_directory  **<----Is there a legitimate way to do this?**
```

so if initially `curdir=1` and `curlevel=0` then
`$(temp)=directory_one`
is equal to

```
dir_1_0=directory_one
```

then later if `curdir=2` and `curlevel=4`, I can reset temp and then have

```
$(temp)=another_directory
```

is the same as

```
dir_2_4=another_directory
```

so I could make a call such as

```
cd $(temp)
```

which will move me to different directories when I need to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is to use `eval`. Like so:

```
 $ foo=bar
 $ bar=baz
 $ eval qux=\$$foo
 $ echo $qux
 baz
```

So what you could do is something like

```
eval temp=\$$"dir_${curdir}_${curlevel}"
cd $temp
```

Comment: Yes! I basically wanted to assign "dir_curdir_curlevel" a specific directory and as curdir and curlevel changed I could access the directory they were referring to and this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

The trick for this is to use `eval` - several times.

```
curdir=1
curlevel=0
temp='dir_${curdir}_${curlevel}'      # Note single quotes!
x=$(eval echo $temp)
eval $x=$PWD
cd /tmp
curdir=2
curlevel=4
x=$(eval echo $temp)
eval $x=$PWD

echo $dir_1_0
echo $dir_2_4
```

The output of `sh -x script`:

```
+ curdir=1
+ curlevel=0
+ temp='dir_${curdir}_${curlevel}'
++ eval echo 'dir_${curdir}_${curlevel}'
+++ echo dir_1_0
+ x=dir_1_0
+ eval dir_1_0=/Users/jleffler/tmp/soq
++ dir_1_0=/Users/jleffler/tmp/soq
+ cd /tmp
+ curdir=2
+ curlevel=4
++ eval echo 'dir_${curdir}_${curlevel}'
+++ echo dir_2_4
+ x=dir_2_4
+ eval dir_2_4=/tmp
++ dir_2_4=/tmp
+ echo /Users/jleffler/tmp/soq
/Users/jleffler/tmp/soq
+ echo /tmp
/tmp
```

The output of `sh script`:

```
/Users/jleffler/tmp/soq
/tmp
```

---

Converted to a function:

```
change_dir()
{
    temp='dir_${curdir}_${curlevel}'      # Note single quotes!
    x=$(eval echo $temp)
    eval $x=$PWD
    cd $1
}

curdir=1
curlevel=0
change_dir /tmp

curdir=2
curlevel=4
change_dir $HOME

echo $dir_1_0
echo $dir_2_4
pwd
```

Output:

```
/Users/jleffler/tmp/soq
/tmp
/Users/jleffler
```

The recorded names are the names of the directory being left, not the one you arrive at.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I need so at the end instead of echoing the answer I could do cd dir_1_0 or cd dir_2_4?

Comment: @Mike: You could do `cd $dir_1_0`, yes (extra dollar sign).

Comment: Note that `bash` supports `${!temp}` which evaluates to the value of the variable named by `${temp}`, so the `x=$(eval echo $temp)` line could be replaced by `x=${!temp}`.

Answer (score 1):

The secure way to do this is to use [indirection, associative arrays (Bash 4), functions or `declare`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006):

Use `declare`:

```
declare $temp=$name_of_directory
```

Use indirection:

```
bar=42
foo=bar
echo ${!foo}
IFS= read -r $foo <<< 101
echo ${!foo}
```

Please take note of the **[security implications of `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)**.